# "philosophical history" / "history of philosophy"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between the meaning of "philosophical history" and "history of philosophy"?

Comment: It depends on context.  What's yours?

Comment: None.  Same idea said two different ways.  If you think there is a difference the word you failed to understand was 'of'.

Comment: On the contrary, there is considerable difference. Philosophical history is history expounded in a philosophical spirit or manner, whatever its subject matter may be. History of philosophy takes the development of philosophic thought for its subject matter--what opinions or doctrines various philosophers held and how their works influenced later philosophers.

Comment: Obviously there are two different possible meanings - you could write [*a philosophical history of language*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+philosophical+history+of+language%22), for example, where your primary focus is language, not philosophy. But *a history of philosophy* would really *have* to have philosophy as its primary focus.

Comment: [The Philosophy of Poverty](http://www.amazon.com/The-Philosophy-Poverty-Pierre-Joseph-Proudhon/dp/1770830154). [The Poverty of Philosophy](http://www.amazon.com/The-Poverty-Philosophy-Karl-Marx/dp/0717807010/).

Answer (score 1):

There is an important distinction to be made. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy#History) defines "history of philosophy" as follows:

> The history of philosophy is the compilation and study of philosophical ideas and concepts through time. Issues specifically related to history of philosophy might include (but are not limited to): How can changes in philosophy be accounted for historically? What drives the development of thought in its historical context? To what degree can philosophical texts from prior historical eras be understood even today? History of philosophy seeks to catalogue and classify such development. The goal is to understand the development of philosophical ideas through time.

As this definition indicates, the history of philosophy is more dependent on tangible, historical events such as wars, famine, religion and how they shaped philosophical thinking at the time.

The next term, "philosophical history" is a little more complex. There is a branch of philosophy known as "The philosophy of history" which discusses "Critical" and "Speculative" philosophy of history. The former being a study into the theory side of the academic discipline of history, the objectiveness of sources and the nature of evidence, while the latter focuses on what can be learned from the processes of human development based on historical evidence (Hegel is well known for this branch of thinking.)

Assuming you weren't referring to this branch of philosophy, the usual context in which I hear "philosophical history" is referring to the process by which a philosophical idea or concept came to be. For example, how did Locke's idea of identity come to be? It began with a rejection of Cartesian rationalists, etc. This is a more common usage of the term, and clearly distinguishes itself from "History of Philosophy."

Comment: Hello, 168, and welcome to ELU. This looks good, but most of us duck questions that need an 'assuming you were / weren't referring to' response.